# Add an iteration variable in a nested for-loop on every iteration

Tags: python-3.x, loops, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a program that prints every possible alphabetical combination between two and four characters. The program as I have it now works just fine, but the implementation is far from ideal. This is what it is now:

```
# make a list that contains ascii characters A to z
ascii = list(range(65, 123))
del ascii[91 - 65 : 97 - 65] # values 91-97 aren't letters

for c1, c2 in product(ascii, repeat=2):
    word = chr(c1) + chr(c2)
    print(word)

for c1, c2, c3 in product(ascii, repeat=3):
    word = chr(c1) + chr(c2) + chr(c3)
    print(word)

for c1, c2, c3, c4 in product(ascii, repeat=4):
    word = chr(c1) + chr(c2) + chr(c3) + chr(c4)
    print(word)
```

I'd much rather have something in the spirit of the following. Forgive me that the following code is totally wrong, I'm trying to convey the spirit of what I thought would be a nicer implementation.

```
iterationvars = [c1, c2, c3, c4]

for i in range(2,5):
    for iterationvars[0:i] in product(ascii, repeat=i):
        word = ??
        print(word)
```

So I have two questions:
1) how can I change the *number of* iteration variables of a nested for loop on every iteration of the 'mother loop'?
2) how can *word* be implemented such that it dynamically adds up all iteration variables, no matter how many there are on that particular iteration.

Of course, very different implementations from what I suggest are also more than welcome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no need to change the number of iteration variables, just keep it all in one tuple then use a joined list comprehension. Something like this would work:

```
for iter_tuple in product(ascii, repeat = i):
    word = ''.join(chr(x) for x in iter_tuple)
    print(word)
```